# How to copy from int[,] to int[] in the kernel?

Tags: arrays, aleagpu

In my kernel I compare two large int[,] lemmaA and lemmaB with each other. they are allocated to the GPU by gpu.Allocate().
my kernel looks like:

```cs
private static void Kernel(int[,] lemmaA, int[,] lemmaB, int[] result, int L, int x)
{
    var start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    var stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    for (var i = start; i < L; i += stride)
    {
       result[i] = Calculate(lemmaA, lemmaB, x, i);
    }
}

public static int Calculate(int[,] lemma1, int[,] lemma2, int x, int i)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z < 40; z++)
    {
      int c1 = lemma1[x, z];
      int c2 = lemma2[i, z];
      r += DoSomething(c1,c2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In the Calculate method I only use a int[] row/array in each int[,] array and I am wondering if I could get an faster execution if I allocated each row/int[] to a **local** array and did the calculation with the **local** arrays.

But how can I copy a row/int[] from the int[,] in the kernel?

```cs
private static void Kernel(int[,] lemmaA, int[,] lemmaB, int[] result, int L, int x)
{
    var start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    var stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    for (var i = start; i < L; i += stride)
    {
       int[] lemma1 = __local__.Array<int>(40);
       COPY(lemma1, lemmaA, a,b,c,d); // <- What to do here ??
       result[i] = Calculate(lemma1, lemma2);
    }
}
public static int Calculate(int[] lemma1, int[] lemma2)
{}
```

Comment: to copy, just do a for loop. `for (var i = 0; i < 40; ++i) lemma1[i] = lemmaA[...];`

Comment: usually this local memory is not efficient. using shared memory might be better.

Comment: Hi Xiang. Thanks for your comment. I was thinking of an equivalent of System.Buffer.BlockCopy. I tried the loop but it was slower than the original.